# Multiple Subscriptions on one observable

Tags: reactiveui

I have a read-write property on my ViewModel and need two separate actions to occur when it changes :

```
 public decimal Paid {
    get { return paid; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref paid, value); }
 }
```

...

in the ctor:

```
this.WhenAnyValue(pb => pb.Paid)
   .Select(amount => NumberToEnglish.ToSentence(amount))
   .ToProperty(this, x => x.AmountInWords, out amountInWords);

this.WhenAnyValue(pb => pb.Paid)
   .Subscribe(amount => SelectedPaymentBatch.Paid = amount );
```

Is there a way to do this in one statement or is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

It's very much feasible to do both in one stream, e.g using `Do` operator (see below), but I would recommend to keep your current approach, as it correctly separates both concerns, which are unrelated but the fact they trigger on the same property (but that could change).

```
this.WhenAnyValue(pb => pb.Paid)
  .Do(amount => SelectedPaymentBatch.Paid = amount)
  .Select(amount => NumberToEnglish.ToSentence(amount))
  .ToProperty(this, x => x.AmountInWords, out amountInWords);
```